# Тире вместо двоеточия (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

Можно это:

> Давайте в один из этих дней: пятница, суббота, воскресенье.

заменить этим?

> Давайте в один из этих дней — пятница, суббота, воскресенье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По [«Лопатину», параграф 36 — примечание](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=97#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5,%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC), можно ставить и тире тоже:

***Давайте в один из этих дней — пятница, суббота, воскресенье***.

Comment: Я из-за того спросил просто, что, если в других случаях те слова можно изъять, в данном так сделать нельзя, так как иначе смысл теряется. *Мы, сэр, можем встретиться в один из этих дней — пятн., субб., воскр.?*

Comment: А как выбрать? Что лучше? Нет выбора –  нет ответа, как я думаю.

Comment: @Sharon Так авторская пунктуация.

Comment: Нет, такой ответ неверный.  Нужно знать особенности каждого знака и применять их в конкретном предложении.  Так что лучше и почему?

Comment: @Sharon Дайте уже свободу. Мы ответили по справочникам. Что лучше – выбор автора. Стиль разговорный. В письменном виде нет никакой разницы, вас поймут и не накажут.

Comment: Справочники все могут прочитать,  А я не знаю, что написать. Два знака сразу  не могу. Помогите!  У двоеточия есть интонационное предупреждение, а у тире нет.

Comment: В письменной речи адресату по барабану интонация.

Comment: По барабану?   Тогда давайте по четным дням писать тире, а по нечетным двоеточие. Или как лучше?

Comment: @Sharon Никак не лучше и не хуже. Давайте так. Мы ничего не сможем посоветовать выбрать. Так как вообще не знаем, что это и откуда. Сколько раз уже было сказано, и Леопольд это видел, что НУЖЕН КОНТЕКСТ. Это переписка? В деловом письме? А может, в личных сообщениях? Это реплика в романе? Это передача слов из интервью?  Поэтому ещё раз: пишущий передаёт своё понимание пунктуации и интонационные ощущения, а читающий, в силу своих знаний об интонационных различиях, воспринимает этот текст. Всё.

Answer (score 4):

Выбирайте, что больше нравится. Я бы выбрал тире.

[***ДВОЕТОЧИЕ — ТИРЕ***](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) (Розенталь):

> Самые многочисленные случаи вариативности знаков препинания — параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире.
>
> **1.** После обобщающего слова перед перечислением однородных членов предложения часто ставится тире (вместо обычного двоеточия): *Там всё иное — **язык, уклад жизни, круг людей*** (Коч.); *Всё в них выражало неприязнь — **их крикливость, самоуверенность, бесцеремонность*** (Гран.); *Возможны другие вспомогательные персонажи — **хозяин** мебельного магазина, перемазанный известью **маляр, зеленщик** из соседней лавки* (Евт.); *Что её больше волнует — **уход** мужа или **то**, что в глазах окружающих перестала существовать «образцовая семья»?* (Газ.); *И отовсюду — из каждого **дома**, **двора**, из каждой **руины** и **переулка** — бежало навстречу нам эхо* (Пауст.).
>
> Ср. примеры, где возможен выбор между двоеточием и тире: *Его ничто не берёт (: —) ни **время**, ни **невзгоды**, ни **болезни**; Конечно, он изменился (: —) **сгорбился, поседел, с морщинками** в уголках рта; Трудно объяснить, чем он привлекал к себе (: —) **интеллигентностью? свободными манерами? искренностью? добротой?**; Но почему он так властвовал над умами и сердцами (: —) **радовал** и **печалил**, **наказывал** и **прощал?**; Мы оба художники (: —) и **ты** и **я.***

Answer (score 1):

Тире может **заменять** двоеточие во многих случаях, так как **интонация** похожая: **понижение** тона перед паузой. Но двоеточие обозначает **интонационное предупреждение** (неполное понижение тона перед подчеркнутой паузой), а тире считается **присоединительным** знаком (полное понижение тона, пауза меньше).

1. **Выбираем двоеточие:**

*В начале недели я буду занят. Давайте в один из **Этих** дней: пятница, суббота, воскресенье.*

Более значимым является **однородный ряд.**

2. **Выбираем тире:**

*В какой день? В общем-то в любой. **ДавАйте** в один из этих дней — пятница, суббота, воскресенье.*

Более значимым является **обобщающее слово.**

Comment: Помните, вы предлагали не обсуждать интонацию? Здесь это бесполезно. Это эфемерно. У меня, например, наоборот, двоеточие обозначает почти полное понижение тона, почти как перед точкой. // "***ДавАйте** в один из этих дней*" вообще не представляю без знака. Если делаем ударение там, где вы поставили, то тогда так:  *ДавАйте... в один из этих дней*.  Если значимым является обобщающее слово, то на него должно падать ударение, как вы поставили в случае двоеточия. Короче, это всё вилами на воде...

Comment: Александр, точное описание интонации я взяла у Кустовой. Поэтому ударение обсуждать не будем. Но значимость ряда и обобщающего слова надо учитывать. Контекст простейший. И что значит ЗДЕСЬ? Это форум лингвистов, так где же еще? Поэтому ваше "по барабану" меня несколько озадачило.  Мы работаем нах письменными текстами, но вам без разницы что писать. Это для меня новость, но ваше дело.  Мне – не по барабану.

Comment: Вы неправильно восприняли мой текст (читаете по диагонали, я помню), вы выхватили жаргонное слово и отнесли его ко мне. Я не говорил, что мне по барабану. // А чтобы слышать, как мы произносим, этот сайт пока не может нам обеспечить. Голосовых нет.

Comment: "В письменной речи адресату по барабану интонация".  А как еще понять?  Не надо употреблять жарг. слова, тогда мне нечего будет выхватывать.

Comment: Так и понять, как написано, а не говорить, что "вам без разницы что писать".

Comment: Нам не дано предугадать,
Как слово наше отзовется...

Comment: Вот-вот... Ладно, простите меня за всё. Закончим, помиримся и будем дружить дальше.

Comment: Агусики, S-ka, семь бед, один ответ)